# php login proces, if rows issues

Tags: php

I have my process login set up, but when I'm trying to change rows to 0 nothing appears so i keep on having to leave the code as 1.

```
<?session_start();
    $usid=$_SESSION["usersid"];
    include "conninfo.php";

    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $query="SELECT * 
              FROM login 
             WHERE username like '$username' AND 
                   password like '$password'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows==1)// change to 0 once login is working
{
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username; //greeting
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
    $usersid=$r["usersid"];
    $_SESSION["usersid"]=$usersid;

    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo "The username and or password you have entered is not recognised";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114). Additionally, you shouldn’t use `LIKE` comparison, otherwise one could log in using `%` for username and/or password.

Comment: This is *not* the right way to handle passwords ever.

Comment: if($rows==1) means the user and password is correct. Why you want to change to 0?

Comment: You **should NOT** match the password on the query and **you SHOULD NOT save password as plain text**. Match only the username and not using LIKE as to avoid ambiguous results and after with the result verify if the password is valid.

Comment: sorry if i seem a bit thick but this is how i was taught by my teacher

Comment: @user3414573 [here is a fine example of login using MySQLi and prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18971788/342740). I am sorry if your teacher taught it with a deprecated library and using `stripslashes` he should go back to school.

Comment: are you doing course from virtual university because they make student to use mysql for basic course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should to use if($rows == 0) to set the session. You have to use if($rows > 0 ) or if($rows == 1 ) then set session .
Fewthings, you have to check like following

- Check whether the form is submitted or not.
- use some encryption    token to check this form is sumbitted from
  your website.
- use  captcha.

  so only the process will work. use this code.

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))  {  // better you check form is submitted or not  
          $username=mysql_real_escapte_string($_POST["username"]);
          $password=mysql_real_escapte_string($_POST["password"]);



      $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username ='$username' AND password ='$password'"; 
      $result=mysql_query($query);

      $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

      if($rows  > 0 )// change to 0 once login is working
      {
      $_SESSION["username"]=$username; //greeting
      $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
      $usersid=$r["usersid"];
      $_SESSION["usersid"]=$usersid;


  header('Location: index.php');
      } else {
  echo "The username and or password you have entered is not recognised";
      }
  }
      ?>
  ```