# I have made a register code but I'm not sure of how to use it to login

Tags: php, mysql

Basically what I need is a php/mysql code to check if a column (username column) is in the same row as the other column (password column) but I'm not sure how to do so, I'm fairly new with working with MySQL. Here's my register code:

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'credentials');
define('DB_USER', 'julianbuscema');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

function NewUser()
{
    $fullname = $_POST['name'];
    $userName = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname,userName,email,pass) VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password')";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($data){
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function SignUp()
{
   if (!empty($_POST['user']))
   { 
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
       if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) { 
          newuser(); 
       } else { 
          echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER..."; 
       } 
   } 
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   SignUp();
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not a question

Comment: `Basically what I need is a php/mysql code` >> [Simple PHP Login](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18971788/342740)

Comment: *"I have made a register code but I'm not sure of how to use it to login"* - That's like an architect who's drawn up plans for a building, but doesn't know how it's put together or where the back door is; *ironic*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple PHP SQL login troubleshooting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971570/simple-php-sql-login-troubleshooting)

Comment: Please learn any popular php framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this basic login page:**

index.php

```
<?php
include('login.php');
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="login-form" >

  <div class="xxxx"><?php echo $error; ?></div>      
  <div class="xxxxx">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="login">
    </div>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("hostname","db_username","db_password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $check_user = "select * from table where username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    $run = mysql_query($check_user);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    header("location: other_page.php"); 
    }
    else {
    $error='Username or password is incorrect!';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Oh sure, give the guy a piece of code and get hacked, good one. You should add a disclaimer.

Comment: Deprecated MySQL library, SQL injection all over, not handling errors if one may happen, plain text password, this is one scary code.

Comment: This is just an basic example.

Comment: @vas_bar_code - yes, it's a basic example of exactly what not to do.